# Unable to read response when status code of fetch call is 500

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am making restful call to a service and getting 500 status code. The response looks like this:

```
{
    "error": true,
    "message": "Test error",
    data: null
}
```

I am using following code to JavaScript side to read the error, but unable to achieve desired result.

```
fetch('your-api-endpoint')
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      return Promise.reject(response)
    }
    return response.json(); // or response.text() depending on the response content type
  })
  .then(data => {
    // Handle successful response data
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
          //How to read the actual response and print it ?
    });
  })
```

I want to read the response and display the `message` property. But the promise is never resolved. Please help

Comment: Of course it's not resolved, you explicitly rejected it, because `!response.ok`.

Comment: What do you mean by _"the promise is never resolved"_?

Comment: @jonrsharpe this promise does resolve thanks to the `.catch()`

Comment: @Phil well, depending on what's done in that callback.

Comment: Maybe you wanted to `await res.json()` either way, then either return or throw the result? It's really not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the type of the `error` and if it's a `Response`, retrieve the body via `.text()` or if you're sure of the format, `.json()`

```js
fetch('https://httpstat.us/500', {
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
})
  .then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      return Promise.reject(response)
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch((error) => {
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      return error.json().then((errData) => {
        console.error('Request failed:', errData);
      });
    }
    console.error(error); // generic error
  });
```

---

If you know the API responds with JSON in all cases, you could always use `.json()` to get the data then make a decision on the response status.

For example (and using async / await because it's objectively cleaner)

```js
(async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('https://httpstat.us/500', {
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
      },
    });

    const data = await res.json();
    if (!res.ok) {
      const err = new Error(`Fetch failed: ${res.status} ${res.statusText}`);
      err.data = data;
      throw err;
    }

    console.log('Success:', data);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    console.error(err.data);
  }
})();
```